# Format currency with symbol before instead of after

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting, converters, currency-formatting

I use a Converter for my TextBox for currency. Everything works great, except that the €-sign is after the value instead of before.

Here is the code:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var dValue = value as decimal?;
    return string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:C}", dValue ?? 0);
}
```

I know I can easily put it before it instead of after like so:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var dValue = value as decimal?;
    return "€ " + string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:C}", dValue ?? 0).Replace("€", "").Trim();
}
```

But I'm just assuming here that there should be a standard in the formatter itself to do this. So, does anyone know how to put the currency before the value instead of behind it using the formatter itself?

For example: With the decimal `12345678.90`, I don't want to display [see first method] `12.345.678,90 €`, but I want to display [see second method] `€ 12.345.678,90` instead.

Comment: @Michael Still doesn't give anything substantial how I should use the German/French CultureInfo, but put the currency symbol before instead of after..

Comment: did you try my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in this way

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var dValue = value as decimal?;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de");
    var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
    nfi.CurrencySymbol = "€";
    return string.Format(nfi,"{0:c}",dValue)
}
```

if it doesn't work try without this line

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de");
```

if it doesn't work again try changing [CurrencyNegativePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx) Property and [CurrencyPositivePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern.aspx) Property with the value of 2

```
nfi.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 2;
nfi.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 2;
```

2 means "€ + number"

Answer (score 0):

Try this (quick code, not really a unit test method, just to see the output).

```
[Test]
public void CurrencySymbolShouldAppearBeforeValue()
{
    decimal price = 1370m;
    var formatInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")
                                .NumberFormat.Clone() as NumberFormatInfo;

    Assert.IsNotNull(formatInfo);

    formatInfo.CurrencyPositivePattern = 2;

    string formated = price.ToString("C3", formatInfo);
    Assert.IsNotNull(formated);
}
```

**Outputs:** *€ 1.370,000*

You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern(v=vs.110).aspx).